# expected template name before '<' token

Tags: c++, linux, templates

I am a newbie to C++. Trying to port a Windows-based program to linux. The platform I use is Ubuntu 13.03. The compiler is g++.

Here is the problematic code.

```
class CMapIDNames : public map< IDKey, string, CIDKeyLess >
{
} mapOfIDNames;
```

The errors are:

> error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token

Tried to include `<functiontal>`, and `namespace::std`, does not help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include `<map>` and refer to is as `std::map`. You also seem to be missing the `<string>` header.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class CMapIDNames : public std::map< IDKey, std::string, CIDKeyLess >
{
};
```

But note that standard library containers are not designed for public inheritance. You should certainly not use them polymorphically.

Comment: Thanks, juanchopanza. This solves the problem. Have a great day!